# Doctrine select query date sqlite

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sqlite

I want to query a db date field via php datetime object with doctrine binding. I get no results on date db field type. It works on datetime db field type.
On mysql and postgres it works.

On Sqlite instead I get this strange behavior. The problem seems linked to the equal comparison only on date field.

Where am I wrong?

This is my entity class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * App\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="Customer")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"base":"BaseCustomer" "extended":"Customer"})
 */
class BaseCustomer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    protected $dateofbirth;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastlogin;
```

In controller:

```
    $datestrchk = "1980-02-05";

    $datedtchk = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datestrchk . " 00:00:00");
    $qb = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array("Customer"))
            ->from("App:Customer", "Customer")
            ->where("Customer.dateofbirth = :data")
            ->setParameter("data", $datedtchk);
    $ret = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo count($ret); // NOT FOUND

    $datedtchk = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $datestrchk);
    $qb = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array("Customer"))
            ->from("App:Customer", "Customer")
            ->where("Customer.dateofbirth = :data")
            ->setParameter("data", $datedtchk);
    $ret = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo count($ret); // NOT FOUND

    $qb = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array("Customer"))
            ->from("App:Customer", "Customer")
            ->where("Customer.dateofbirth = :data")
            ->setParameter("data", $datestrchk);
    $ret = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo count($ret); // OK

    $date1start = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "1980-02-04 23:59:59");
    $date1end = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "1980-02-05 00:00:00");

    $qb = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array("Customer"))
            ->from("App:Customer", "Customer")
            ->where("Customer.dateofbirth >= :data1start AND Customer.dateofbirth <= :data1end")
            ->setParameter("data1start", $date1start)
            ->setParameter("data1end", $date1end);
    $ret = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo count($ret); // OK

    $date2start = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "1980-02-05 00:00:00");
    $date2end = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "1980-02-05 00:00:01");

    $qb = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array("Customer"))
            ->from("App:Customer", "Customer")
            ->where("Customer.dateofbirth >= :data2start AND Customer.dateofbirth <= :data2end")
            ->setParameter("data2start", $date2start)
            ->setParameter("data2end", $date2end);
    $ret = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo count($ret); // NOT FOUND
```

Code: https://github.com/ComuneFI/BiCoreBundle
(Customer->Cliente)

Symfony 3.4.18

Sqlite db version 3.22

Php 7.2.12 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: How are your date strings formatted in the database? What do `date1start` etc. look like when stringified? Is it a different format?

Comment: Sqlite create: CREATE TABLE Customer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, dateofbirth DATE NOT NULL, lastlogin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL);

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Try `->setParameter("data2start", $date2start->format('Ymd H:i:s'))`

Comment: I'm trying to build a multi database "framework" with doctrine and I need the parameter to be exactly datetime